# ant: copy file from remote location on windows

Tags: windows, ant, filesystems, unc

I want to copy a file present in a shared location to windows machine. Is there some way by which i can specify username and password while copying the file?

If i try to access using copy task, it is giving error saying location does not exist. is it because of permission?

```
<copy todir="C:/localdir">
    <fileset dir="\\\remotemachinename\dirname"> 
    </fileset> 
</copy>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have the address wrong.

I just tried the following tests successfully(2 slashes):

```
dir="\\remotemachinename\dirname"
dir="//remotemachinename/dirname"
```

But this was unsuccessful (3 backslashes):

```
dir="\\\remotemachinename\dirname"
```

However, no password was required for the directory I was accessing.

Answer (score 2):

A  backslash is an escape character. In order to use a backslash as a backslash you have to use `\\` for each slash. So your path should be

`\\\\remotemachine\\dirname`

Alternatively as sudocode suggests, use a forward slashes instead.