# Fetch/Download jar from shared location using ant

Tags: ant, build-tools

We have some jar's (project dependencies) at a shared location (i.e. \machine\jar). Currently, we copy these jar files manually from that shared location and add them to our project to resolve build dependencies.

I'm writing an Ant script to automate a few of our tasks. I was wondering if there is a way to copy these jars from the shared location to local system through ant script?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy the jars using Ant FileSet.

```
 <target name="copy">
  <copy todir="location_to_copy">
    <fileset dir="share_location"> 
    </fileset> 
  </copy> 
 </target>
```

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html

[ant: copy file from remote location on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094362/ant-copy-file-from-remote-location-on-windows)